# Blender how to have different pictures for hdri light and background of a scene?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, lighting, hdri

i have a question about the background in a blender scene. i have a scene with a house and with an HDRI in the scene world that serves as a light. so far so good. but now the hdri doesn't look good as a background/sky and i want to use a different image for it. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Use the Is *Camera Ray* output of an *Input > Light Path* node as a factor in a mix between your 2 HDRI images:

[image]